# Increase the duration of the Floating Thumbnail screenshot preview on macOS

Tags: macos, screenshot, thumbnails, preview, duration

So there are these helpful floating previews on the few latest macOS versions. But I can't seem to find any way to increase the duration of a preview (the default is 5 seconds). Is it even possible? Quite often it's sliding away while I'm looking for a window to drop it to. And it's very frustrating.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a way to configure the duration of a screenshot preview.

```
 defaults write com.apple.screencaptureui "thumbnailExpiration" -float 30 && killall SystemUIServer
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Sometimes it needs to reboot, to apply changes

Comment: Perfect, tested with macOS Ventura 13.2.1. No reboot required. Thanks @Antigp

Comment: Works perfectly